# Acceso HTTP a PC conectada a Wi-Fi con anclaje USB de un teléfono desde otro dispositivo de la red local

Tags: android, ubuntu, apache2, redes

Desde que se me rompió el cable de red (de unos 30mts) estoy usando un teléfono viejo (Android) para darle internet a mi computadora por medio del anclaje de red USB.

Estoy queriendo acceder a una página hosteada en mi PC (Ubuntu20.04) desde otro teléfono en la misma red local, pero aparentemente su IP no es visible para otros dispositivos (sólo puedo acceder desde el teléfono conectado por USB). Vi que se podría solucionar corriendo un servidor en el teléfono descargando alguna aplicación, pero me gustaría evitarlo.

¿Hay alguna manera de configurarlo para que la IP de mi PC sea visible en la red local sin tener que correr un servidor web en el teléfono que uso para darle internet?

-- ACTUALIZACIÓN --

**Router**:

IP: `192.168.1.1`

Mask: `255.255.255.0`

**Teléfono** conectado a la PC:

IP1: `192.168.1.xxx`

IP2(al activar anclaje de red): `192.168.xxx.xxx`

**PC**:

IP: `192.168.xxx.xxx`

DNS y DefaultRoute: `*IP2 del teléfono*`

Comment: Ponle ip fija dentro del rango de red local a tu PC, así siempre tendrás acceso fijo a dicho pc desde cualquier dispositivo de la red local. Otra posibilidad, sería a través de un servicio gratuito de ip dinámica,configurar tu red para acceder a ella desde el exterior.

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar. Estoy probando eso que dijiste y estaba pensando que quizás cambiando la máscara de red del router podría llegar a reconocer la red que crea el teléfono dentro de la red local. Actualicé la pregunta para agregar información que faltaba.

Comment: @N.N. deduzco que, aunque las direcciones estén en el mismo segmento de red no implica que vaya a haber conexión, piensa que el teléfono tiene una tabla de enrutamiento propia, lo cual haría como una especie de VLAN. No creo que esto se pueda configurar a nivel de configuración del teléfono... Mira a ver si por ADB hay algún archivo de red

Comment: Uh, que bueno eso! Gracias!